# How can I finish the gap between the stairs and the drywall?

Tags: drywall, stairs

Gap between the stairs and the wall.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would help if we could see more context. Whatever you do should coordinate with the rest of your trim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're stuck with the gap, look in the trim/molding section of your home store for quarter round or shoe molding. There are many types to choose from. Below are some pictures of the quarter and shoe trim.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Between a staircase and a wall you're supposed to have a piece of trim called a **skirtboard** to fill that gap.  It functions like a baseboard to keep peoples' shoes & feet from scuffing up the walls.

I suggest you look for a book called [Building Stairs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LTYC3C4) by Andy Engel.  Many libraries have it.  Staircases are really complex with more parts than I realized before getting this book!

[image: Parts of a staircase]

Comment: Skirtboards aren't usually used with closed staircases. The stringer already acts as a skirt. Ideally, the stringer would've been installed to framing, not drywall, mostly eliminating this problem.

Comment: But you still have to finish off the bottom, slanted edge of the drywall which now "rests" on the stringer?

Comment: In this question/thread, the picture shows drywall outside of the stringers; not above them.  The whole thing looks unusual to me.